# If radix tries (or say HAT tries) are so good for storing & managing strings, why can't they be used just as well for integers?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashtable, trie

I'm assuming they can, just treating a number by it's 32 (or 64) bit binary "string", for example. And in this case, are hash tables (say cache conscious hash tables) still on top of things when it comes to fast insertion/retrieval?

Comment: One possibility springs to mind, not an answer because I don't know whether it's correct. Even though integers can be treated as strings, they are very *short* strings, just 4 or 8 bytes. That *might* be enough to produce rather different efficiency considerations. But AFAIK, radix tries are perfectly plausible in performance for storing ints whether they're "provably the best known" or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, tries are particularly useful at storing strings because we're often concerned with the prefix of a string (e.g., auto-completion) and tries excel at prefix searches.  It is rare to be concerned with the prefix of integers.

Comment: Oh yes this is a very good point. I posted this after reading a paper by Askitis and Sinha (http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV62Askitis.pdf) where only insertion/retrieval was being looked at..and because with smaller sets you can sometimes beat the cost of computing a hash i was thinking why not..